# How to get a custom grid param in jqGrid jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

net web forms project and I get data with this format from my ashx.cs http handler file (server side) :

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":10,"userData":{"KoleMoamelat":"1180"},"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["1"]}]}
```

and this is a part of the my jqGrid jquery code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var grid;
      grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
          url: '/Report/Handlers/AdvancedSearch.ashx',
          datatype: 'json',
          mtype: 'GET',
          colNames: [ 'نوع ملک'],
          colModel: [
              { name: 'Counter', index: 'Counter', width: 40, align: 'center' },
 pager: jQuery('#pager'),
 rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
 rowNum: 10,
 height: 120,
 sortname: 'Id',
 sortorder: "desc",
 viewrecords: true,
 imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
 caption: 'آمار قراردادهای ثبت شده در یک بازه زمانی',
 loadComplete: function (data) {
     var userData = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
     document.getElementById("lblKoleMoamelat").innerHTML = userData["KoleMoamelat"];
```

actually the data for the jqGrid table itself is correct without any problem, but I want to access the userData that returned with the jQgrid columns for this segment of code :

```
document.getElementById("lblKoleMoamelat").innerHTML = userData["KoleMoamelat"];
```

but this code doesn't get userData from ashx.cs response (server response) :

```
var userData = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");
```

now in html form the element of Id : lblKoleMoamelat unfortunately shows undefined.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You have to add to the colModel the properties you want to get

Comment: How can I do this for userData property? because it is not in the rows

Comment: but I want to show userData values in another part of the form, not the data

Comment: Does data.userData[0]["KoleMoamelat"] contain something?

Comment: No, unfortunately I wite it in console.log and it throws exception: Unable to get property 'userData' of undefined or null reference. Means that data parameter is undefined or null

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the code snippet that should help you access the `userData` from the response and update the HTML element with the correct value:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid;
    grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/Report/Handlers/AdvancedSearch.ashx',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['نوع ملک'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Counter', index: 'Counter', width: 40, align: 'center' },
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        rowNum: 10,
        height: 120,
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
        caption: 'آمار قراردادهای ثبت شده در یک بازه زمانی',
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            var userData = data.userData; // Access userData directly from the response data
            document.getElementById("lblKoleMoamelat").innerHTML = userData["KoleMoamelat"];
        }
    });
</script>
```

You should access the `userData` directly from the `data` parameter of the `loadComplete` function. The `userData` is already part of the response data, so you don't need to use the `getGridParam` method to access it.

Comment: I used the code you provided and log the userData to see what is in it, but unfortunately it is an empty array and doesnt show any thing